# How to undo redirect of cin on this code?

Tags: c++, io, stream, file-descriptor

I have used dup2() on the code bellow and now I am having problems on getting cin to read from screen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

shared_ptr<string[]> getP_string(const char* cmd){
    unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> input(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    int backInput = dup(0);
    dup2(fileno(input.get()),0);
    streambuf* stream_buffer_cin= cin.rdbuf();  
    if(!input){
        cerr << "won't open" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int count=0;
    int test;
    for (test=fgetc(stdin); test!=EOF; test=fgetc(stdin)){
        if (char(test) == '\n') count ++;
        cout << (char)test;
    }
    shared_ptr<string[]> results(new string[count]);
    cin.rdbuf(stream_buffer_cin); ///reading the cout above
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        cin >> results[i];
    }
    close(fileno(input.get()));
    dup2(backInput,0);
    close(backInput);
    return results;
}
```

part of what I used (lines 15, 33, 34 and 35) came from here: [how to undo dup2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500000/undo-redirect-of-stdout-with-dup2)

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of a `shared _ptr` to an array of `string`s, see if you can use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Instead of redirecting and then re-redirecting, ask yourself, "What do I get from redirecting in the first place?" and "Is it worth complicating my code?"

Comment: Have you already tried and rejected opening the file normally and reading directly from the file stream?

Comment: I am trying to use fgets now but I am being unsuccessful on rewinding the file

Answer (score 0):

`streambuf* stream_buffer_cin = cin.rdbuf();` doesn't save the state of the stream, so doing `cin.rdbuf(stream_buffer_cin)` won't rewind the file, just sets the pointer to the same thing. Instead of trying to rewind the file, just use a `std::string` which will grow as you insert.

```
std::string getP_string(const char* cmd) {
  unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> input(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
  int backInput = dup(0);
  dup2(fileno(input.get()), 0);
  streambuf* stream_buffer_cin = cin.rdbuf();
  if (!input) {
    cerr << "won't open" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  std::string results;
  std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin), {},
            std::back_inserter(results));

  close(fileno(input.get()));
  dup2(backInput, 0);
  close(backInput);
  return results;
}
```